# Equivalent of alias for a symbolic link?

Tags: symlink, cd-command

I find myself needing to jump around a few directories in my home folder often and get tired of writing them. I would like a quicker approach, which would traditionally be a symbolic link.

However, I don't want to clutter up my home directory with dozens of symbolic links. I could create some `~/links/` directory and clutter *it* with symbolic links, but it still is ugly. Besides, I may want to create symbolic links which change each day (defined in .bashrc) to jump to present days directory.

Is there a way to effectively alias a symbolic link, creating something that will be recognized as a link for quick navigation, but won't actually appear when I do an `ls` of my home directory, and won't last beyond the current session?

Comment: you may want to look into pushd and popd

Comment: i find Jeroen Janssen's approach to be adaptable and low-cost for this exact need: http://jeroenjanssens.com/2013/08/16/quickly-navigate-your-filesystem-from-the-command-line.html

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @Theophrastus Heh — that's basically what I reimplemented not quite as elegantly in my answer.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/874574/how-do-you-cd-to-the-directory-of-another-screen-window.  If you use `screen`, that's a way to get other shells `cd`ed to the location of one where you typed out the full path.  I've had it in my .bashrc since writing that post, and use it fairly often.

Comment: not exactly what you are looking for, but still might come in handy when jumping back and forth between two directoris: `cd -` will `cd` into the last directory were previously.  Hence, if you do it twice you'll go back to where you started... very nice for the situation "oh i forgot to edit someFile.txt at the previous location" => Simply: `cd -`, edit someFile.txt `cd -`

Comment: @dingalapadum a good comment, and I will likely use that.  I'm always looking to increase my knowledge of linux shortcuts (the real problem is retaining them, I swear I keep forgeting VI shortcuts between uses lol)

Comment: As a completely different suggestion, and assuming you are using a GUI, perhaps several different windows? I have 5-10 different directories I need to work in, and have a shell window for each, with each window on its own virtual desktop. When switching to another work task, and its directory, I switch desktops.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shell aliases have the feature that you can do (some) name-completion on them (usually bound to <kbd>tab</kbd>).  Alternatively, you can use the `CDPATH` feature, which "recently" (within the past 5-6 years) has been improved to support name-completion.  If that works for you, it has the advantage that the what you type is the actual name of the directory rather than a mnemonic for it.

According to the bash manual

> **`CDPATH`**
>   A colon-separated list of directories used as a search path for the **`cd`** builtin command.

Further reading:

- [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)
- [Some Bash tricks: CDPATH and ~/.inputrc](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~razvan/blog/some-bash-tricks-cdpath-and-inputrc/)
- [Use CDPATH to access frequent directories in bash](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2005031814311425)
- [bash: Is there a way to use tab completion through out CDPATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/216803/bash-is-there-a-way-to-use-tab-completion-through-out-cdpath)
- [CDPATH Bash completion in OSX](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/cdpath-bash-completion-in-osx)

Comment: Did not know about the `CDPATH` environment variable, thank you.  I might add my `git_repos` directory to that variable....

Answer (score 17):

For the directories you frequent often, but don't change daily, another option is just to have several `alias` commands in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias cdo="cd /u01/app/oracle"
alias cdw="cd /var/www/html"
```

A friend has about 50 of those; I have a handful; quick and easy.  Just

```
cdo
```

to change directory to /u01/app/oracle

Comment: Indeed.  I have used this mechanism since the early 1990s.

Answer (score 14):

You could use tab completion. By default on many Linux distributions, bash is set up so that when you hit the [TAB] key, you're given a list of possible matches, or if there's just one match, it's all filled out. For cd, this is normally a list of subdirectories of the current working directory. You could overwrite that, but I suggest instead making an alias, like `jd` for "jump directory":

```
alias jd=cd
```

and then, defining the "bookmarks" you want as completions for jd. Look at the bash man page for a lot more options (including auto-generating the results on the fly from a command or function), but the easiest way is just a list of words, with `-W`:

complete -W "/srv/www ~/tmp ~/work" jd

Now, type `jd` and hit [TAB], and you'll see your "bookmarks". Type any ambiguous part, and then hit [TAB] to complete. (In the above, the `~`s expand to my home directory, so the first [TAB] gives me a `/`, and if I hit `w` and [TAB] again, `/srv/www` is filled out.)

Of course, put this in `~/.bash_profile` to make it persist.

Or, we can take this to the next level. Make a directory `~/.shortcuts` — starting with a dot, it'll be hidden and not muss up your nice clean home directory — and fill that with symlinks to your desired directories. Then, put *this* in your ~/.bash_profile:

```
_list_shortcuts() 
{ 
    COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( ls ~/.shortcuts )" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} ))
}
jd()
{
    cd -P ~/.shortcuts/$1
}
complete -F _list_shortcuts jd
```

This defines a slightly more complicated completion in the fuction `_list_shortcuts` to build the list of names, and makes `jd` be a function rather than a simple alias, since we want it to act differently from just `cd`. The `-P` flag to `cd` makes it resolve the symlinks, so everything becomes transparent magic. Your shortcut names don't even have to match the targets.

So:

```
$ ls -l ~/.shortcuts/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mattdm mattdm 16 Dec 17 19:44 tmp -> /home/mattdm/tmp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mattdm mattdm 17 Dec 17 19:44 WORK -> /home/mattdm/work
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mattdm mattdm  8 Dec 17 19:44 www -> /srv/www
$ jd tmp
$ pwd
/home/mattdm/tmp
$ jd WORK
/home/mattdm/work
```

And, for an extra dose of fancy, make `jd` list all of your shortcuts when executed without any parameters:

```
jd()
{
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
      (cd ~/.shortcuts; stat -c '%N' *)
    else
      cd -P ~/.shortcuts/$1
    fi
}
```

---

*Note: I use `compgen -W $( cmd )` instead of `compgen -C 'cmd'` because the latter never works for me and I don't understand why. That  might be a new question of my own. :)*

Comment: very interesting.  One catch though, it still requires typing out the full link, or at least enough of the link to become non-ambiguous, before I can complete with jd.  Any way to add aliases to the jd commands to shorten them?  or make them relative to a directory where I can store symbolic links I suppose.

Comment: @dsollen See update :)

Comment: this worked perfectly.  In all honesty I didn't expect a good answer to this question, but this is pretty much exactly what I wanted.  I anticipate quite a bit of use of this and it feels clean enough to add to the list of things I modify whenever I get a new VM (I even have an automated way to clone my standard environmental changes to a new vm lol).  Thanks alot.  At some point when I have more free time I'll figure out how the syntax for the COMPREPLY works ;)

Answer (score 7):

I recommend `pushd` and `popd`.

I personally do find them handy when doing development work / reading source code, when multiple directories are involved.

They effectively implement a stack structure/LIFO, where you PUSH a directory (`pushd`), and the next POP directory command (`popd`) retrieves it.

So, when inside a dir, you would do:

```
pushd .
```

And when you need to retrieve it, you do

```
popd
```

You can perform multiple `pushd` (s), and do the corresponding `popd` (s) later on, to return to the directories.

I will leave here a link.

http://www.eriwen.com/bash/pushd-and-popd/

Comment: This is the solution I use also, with the exception that I don't use `popd` much.  I fill my `dirs` list (which is populated by `pushd` commands) with all the directories I want to visit/work in for that chunk of time, then I run `pushd +1`.  Then, I can cycle through the directories with a simple `!pu` which is *very* fast.  (Note that on both Ubuntu and CentOS, `pushd` is the *only* command available on a clean install that starts with `pu`.)

Answer (score 3):

You could just put them as variables in your `~/.bashrc`, and then they're only a `$` away.

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
if [ "$PS1" ]
then
    export myproj=~/todays/fancy/project
fi

$ cd $myproj
```

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is **variables**, those symbolic things in the shell that stand for other things, similarly to symbolic links in the filesystem.

```
path/to/project $ project=$PWD
path/to/project $ cd $elsewhere   # Previously created
path/to/elsewhere $ cd $project
path/to/project $ logout          # Variables gone, as required
```

In any decent shell, you get <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion on variable names which further helps.